# I'm writing the ATM code. I completed it, but the value of the result file continues to appear as strange symbols or alphabets in No. 4

Tags: java, encoding

After making a deposit in the work I deposit, the text file doesn't show numbers and strange symbols continue to appear. How should I fix it?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ATM {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Choose the work you used.");
            System.out.println(" 1. Opening an account.\n 2. Check the balance.\n 3. Transfer.\n 4. Deposit\n 5. Withdrawal\n 0. End");

            int num;
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String input = scanner.next();
            num = Integer.parseInt(input);

            if (num == 1) {
                System.out.println("Enter the account number you want to open.");
                String id = scanner.next();

                FileWriter writer1 = null;

                try {
                    String baseId = "1111-51-";
                    writer1 = new FileWriter(baseId + id, false);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Opening an account failed.");
                    continue;
                }
                try {
                    writer1.write("0");
                    writer1.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("There was an error opening an account.");
                    continue;
                }
            }

            else if (num == 2) {
                System.out.println("Enter an account to check the balance.");

                Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                String id = scanner2.nextLine();

                FileInputStream inputStream = null;
                try {
                    inputStream = new FileInputStream(id);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    System.out.println("The account does not exist.");
                    continue;
                }

                System.out.println("Outputs the balance of the." + id);

                Scanner reader = new Scanner(inputStream);

                while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
                    System.out.println(reader.nextLine());
                }
                System.out.println("\n");

                reader.close();
            }

            else if (num == 3) {
//I'm going to make it.
            }

            else if (num == 4) {
                System.out.println("Enter the account you want to deposit.");
                Scanner scanner4 = new Scanner(System.in);
                String id = scanner4.next();

                FileInputStream inputStream = null;
                try {
                    inputStream = new FileInputStream(id);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    System.out.println("The account does not exist.");
                    continue;
                }
                Scanner reader1 = new Scanner(inputStream);

                FileWriter writer2 = null;
                FileWriter writer3 = null;

                File file = new File(id);
                Scanner scanner0 = new Scanner(file);
                int i;
                i = scanner0.nextInt();

                try {
                    writer3 = new FileWriter(id, false);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("There was an error in the deposit.");
                    continue;
                }

                try {
                        System.out.println("|\n|\n|\nv");
                        System.out.println("Enter the amount you want to deposit.");
                        String money = scanner4.next();
                        int m = Integer.parseInt(money);
                        writer3.write(i + m);
                        writer3.flush();
                        writer3.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        System.out.println("An error occurred during the deposit.");
                }
                scanner0.close();
            }

            else if (num == 5) {
//I'm going to make it.
            }

            else if (num == 0) {
                System.out.println("Exit the program.");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you enter the price to deposit in the fourth deposit, the value in the result file has a strange symbol, so what's the reason for this and how should I fix it?

For your information, the unit of money is Korea's 'won'.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the line

```
writer3.write(i + m);
```

since `writer3` is a `FileWriter`. Internally, the `int` parameter is cast to `char` which results in the ascii value of that int to be printed.

The solution is to use use this change:

```
writer3.write(String.valueOf(i + m));
```

which makes sure that your number is treated as a String.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the amount back to a string probably using sprintf().

In your current implementation you are writing a raw integer to the file.